# Input menu contents do not overflow row box in flexdashboard

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard, selectinput

I am creating a reactive dashboard using flexdashboard with shiny. I would like the first row below the header to contain two separate selectInput() menus. I am keeping the height of the rows small (50), because there will be several more graphs underneath and I need the space. However, when the dashboard is rendered, clicking on the input menu to select another option results in the dropdown "disappearing" behind the row (not overflowing it). This makes it difficult to select items below the second or third element. How do I make the contents overflow? Here is a reproducible code + screenshot:

````
---
title: "Test Dashboard"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: fill
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
```

Row {data-height=50}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Window 1

```{r}
selectInput("project", label = NULL, choices = c("A","B","C","D"))
```

### Window 2
```{r}
selectInput("data", label = NULL, choices = c("1","2","3","4","5", "6"))
```


Row
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart B

```{r}
renderPlot({
  plot(rnorm(1000), type = "l", main = paste("Project:",input$project, " Data:", input$data))
})
```
````

Attached an image of how it looks.

Flexdasboard image:

[image]

Thanks much,

Jorge

Answer (score 0):

You said there will be more graphs in the future, but I think you can render the individual plots 'underneath' Flexdashboard, to save space. I changed, the rows to columns, let me know.

````
---
title: "Test Dashboard"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: fill
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
```

Column {data-width=600}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Window 1

```{r}
selectInput("project", label = NULL, choices = c("A","B","C","D"))
```

### Window 2
```{r}
selectInput("data", label = NULL, choices = c("1","2","3","4","5", "6"))
```


Column {data-width=400}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart B

```{r}
renderPlot({
  plot(rnorm(1000), type = "l", main = paste("Project:",input$project, " Data:", input$data))
})
```
````

Comment: Thank you Daniel, but I do want to keep this design with the two (or 3) selectInput menus in a row. Here is an example (using shiny) of how it should look: https://jaap.shinyapps.io/powerSensor/