# Adjusting Border Widths in R

Tags: r

I found this stackoverflow post here ([Input menu contents do not overflow row box in flexdashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62266111/input-menu-contents-do-not-overflow-row-box-in-flexdashboard)) and I slightly adapted the code:

````
---
title: "Test Dashboard"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: fill
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
```

Column {data-width=600}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Window 1

```{r}
selectInput("project", label = NULL, choices = c("A","B","C","D"))
```


Column {data-width=400}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart B

```{r}
renderPlot({
  plot(rnorm(1000), type = "l", main = paste("Project:",input$project, " Data:", input$data))
})
```
````

[image]

**Is it possible to adjust this code so that output looks something like this?**

[image]

I tried adjusting different values of  `Column {data-width=600}` and `Column {data-width=400}` ... but nothing seems to be working.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put them in the same chunk or leave them separate, the only part that matters if you want them in the same row is that they're in the same row. For example:

````
Column {data-width=600}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Window 1 {data-height=500}

```{r puts}
selectInput("project", label = NULL, choices = c("A","B","C","D"))

```

```{r plottty}

plot_ly(mtcars, x = ~mpg, y = ~am, type = "bar", height = 400)

```
````

Did you notice that I added a row height and a height to the plot? That's because Plotly will ignore `fig.height` and `out.height`. It will render at the height of its parent here, but with the search bar, that drops part of the plot below what you can see. When you define the row height and the plot height, you avoid this problem.

[image]

---

---

Since you asked (not here) about this, I thought I would add about "The Jones' House" (Yeah, I know it's spelled different in the code, but I can't but feel like grammatically it's all wrong...but how can I say that about someones else's name, ya know?) Anyway...

````
Bedroom {data-navmenu='The Joneses House'}
=====================================

More info...

Kitchen {data-navmenu='The Joneses House'}
=====================================

### Window 1 {data-height=500}

```{r boxy}

shiny::selectInput('big things', label = NULL, choices = LETTERS[1:4])

```


```{r plotty}

plot_ly(mtcars, x = ~mpg, y = ~am, type = "bar", height = 400)

```
````

[image]

Comment: Hi Kat! I have been trying to work on this plotly problem over here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74216958/restructuring-grouped-data-in-r . Do you have any ideas about this one? Thank you!