# Restructuring Grouped Data in R

Tags: r, visualization

I have this data in the following format:

```
my_data = structure(list(name = c("john", "john", "john", "john", "john", 
"alex", "alex", "alex", "alex", "alex", "tim", "tim", "tim", 
"tim", "tim", "jason", "jason", "jason", "jason", "jason", "peter", 
"peter", "peter", "peter", "peter", "nancy", "nancy", "nancy", 
"nancy", "sarah", "sarah", "sarah", "sarah", "luke", "luke", 
"luke", "luke", "steve", "steve", "steve", "steve", "matt", "matt", 
"matt", "mark", "mark", "mark", "jim", "jim", "jim", "derek", 
"derek", "lucy", "lucy", "anne", "kevin", "dave"), year = c(2010, 
2011, 2013, 2014, 2019, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2008, 2010, 
2014, 2018, 2019, 2005, 2006, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 
2015, 2016, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2019, 2020, 2007, 
2008, 2009, 2010, 2009, 2015, 2016, 2016, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2009, 
2015, 2016, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2005, 2012, 
2011), grade = c("PASS", "PASS", "PASS", "FAIL", "FAIL", "FAIL", 
"PASS", "FAIL", "FAIL", "PASS", "PASS", "PASS", "PASS", "PASS", 
"PASS", "PASS", "FAIL", "FAIL", "FAIL", "PASS", "FAIL", "PASS", 
"FAIL", "FAIL", "PASS", "FAIL", "FAIL", "PASS", "FAIL", "PASS", 
"FAIL", "PASS", "FAIL", "PASS", "PASS", "FAIL", "FAIL", "PASS", 
"PASS", "PASS", "PASS", "PASS", "PASS", "FAIL", "PASS", "PASS", 
"PASS", "PASS", "FAIL", "PASS", "PASS", "FAIL", "FAIL", "FAIL", 
"PASS", "PASS", "FAIL")), row.names = c(NA, -57L), class = "data.frame")
```

This data shows for each student:

- The year they were enrolled in school
- If they passed or failed for that year

In this dataset, students have been attended school for different periods of time. Sometimes, students take a leave of absence and then return to the school.

I would like to make a "Sankey Diagram" (e.g. https://d2mvzyuse3lwjc.cloudfront.net/doc/en/UserGuide/images/Sankey_Diagrams/Sankey_Diagrams_01.png?v=83374) that looks at the academic history of the different students in such a way:

[image]

I found this link in R that shows how to do something similar : https://rpubs.com/techanswers88/sankey-with-own-data-in-ggplot

But I am not sure as to how I can restructure the data to make such a diagram.

Can someone please suggest how I can restructure this data so that I can make this diagram? **Possibly in plotly?** https://plotly.com/r/sankey-diagram/

Thank you!

Comment: i read the  ggsankey link you shared, they use `make_long` function inside that package, which looks simple (altough i did not try) If it were your data it would be `d <- my_data %>%  make_long(name, year, grade)`.  Are you gonna use that package?

Answer (score 3):

You could first transform your data to wide based on each year using `pivot_wider`. After transforming the data back to wide using `make_long` and the tricky part is to replace the NA values with a previous value in the data to prevent it from plotting NA's in your graph. Here is a reproducible example:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggsankey)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# Transform data to wide based on year
my_data_wide <- my_data %>% 
  group_by(year) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = year, values_from = grade) %>%
  select(-row) %>%
  select(sort(names(.)))

# Transform data back to long format and replace na's
df <- my_data_wide %>% make_long(`2005`:`2022`) %>% filter(!if_all(c(node, next_node), is.na)) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(node = ifelse(is.na(node), next_node, node),
         next_node = ifelse(is.na(next_node), node, next_node))

# Plot
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, next_x = next_x, node = node, next_node = next_node, fill = factor(node), label = node)) + 
  geom_sankey(flow.alpha = 0.5, node.color = "black", show.legend = FALSE) + 
  geom_sankey_label(size = 2, color = "black", fill= "white", hjust = 0.5) +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  theme(axis.title = element_blank(), axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.ticks = element_blank(), panel.grid = element_blank())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much! Is it possible to do this in plotly?

Answer (score 3):

You could use calculate next grade for every student and use `ggsankey`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggsankey)
library(ggplot2)

sankey_data <- my_data %>% arrange(name,year) %>%
                group_by(name) %>%
                mutate(next_year=lead(year),
                       next_grade=lead(grade)) %>%
                ungroup

ggplot(sankey_data, aes(x = year, 
               next_x = next_year, 
               node = grade, 
               next_node = next_grade,
               fill = factor(grade))) +
  geom_sankey()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Is it possible to do this in plotly? https://plotly.com/r/sankey-diagram/

Comment: @antonoyaro8, `plotly::ggplotly()` seems to work on above plot.