# Sending an Email Through HTML

Tags: html, r

I found the following HTML code for sending an e-mail:

```html
<html>
   <body>
      <h2> Questions? Send an e-mail! </h2>
      <form action="mailto:antonoyaro_9999999999999@hotmail.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
         Name:<br>
         <input type="text" name="name"><br>
         E-mail:<br>
         <input type="text" name="mail"><br>
         Comment:<br>
         <input type="text" name="comment" size="50"><br><br>
         <input type="submit" value="Send">
         <input type="reset" value="Reset">
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Since I am using the R programming language, I copied this HTML code into an R Markdown editor and then ran the code:

[image]

When I click send, I get the following window:

[image]

**Is it possible to modify this HTML code so that only the message text appears in the e-mail body? For example:**

[image]

Any ideas on how to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: is this really a pure html? because if it is your client side will just take a default email they were using. I would suggest you explore on php to make this more customizable.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! Do you have any idea how to do this in R?

Comment: I dont use R honestly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for an RMD output set to `html_document`. You needed to identify the email as an email and the body as the body (`comment` isn't recognized).

Notice that each part of the form is wrapped in a label.

Let me know if you have questions.

```html
<body>
  <h2> Questions? Send an e-mail! </h2>
  <form action="mailto:antonoyaro_9999999999999@hotmail.com" method="get" enctype="text/plain">
    <div>
      <label for="name">Name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /><br>
    </label>
    </div>
    <div><label for="email">Email:<br>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" /><br>
    </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="body">
    Comment:<br>
    <textarea name="body" placeholder="Send your comments."></textarea><br><br>
    </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="submit" value="Send" name="submit" />
      <input type="reset" value="Reset" name="reset" />
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "me"
date: "2022-10-23"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = F)
```

<body>
<h2> Questions? Send an e-mail! </h2>
<form action="mailto:antonoyaro_9999999999999@hotmail.com" method="get" enctype="text/plain">
<div>
<label for="name">Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" /><br>
</label>
</div>
<div><label for="email">Email:<br>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" /><br>
</label>
</div>
<div>
<label for="body">
Comment:<br>
<textarea name="body" placeholder="Send your comments."></textarea><br><br>
</label>
</div>
<div>
<input type="submit" value="Send" name="submit" />
<input type="reset" value="Reset" name="reset" />
</div>
</form>
</body>
````

Comment: Hi Kat! Thank you so much for your answer! When I try to "knit" your code to an HTML Document or to a Flexdashboard, I get the following output: https://imgur.com/a/GlObVNg .... am I doing something wrong? Thanks so much!

Comment: I added the entire RMD code I used. Can you see if that works?

Comment: Now everything is working fine! Thank you!